# How to include background into R plot?

Tags: r, image

My code:

```
x <-sample(1:1484)
y <-sample(1:1484)


library(hexbin)
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("darkorchid4","darkblue","green","yellow", "red") )
plot(hexbin(vel1,res1),colorcut = seq(0,1,length.out=24),colramp = function(n) cols(24))
```

Counts in the legend are from one to seven(e.g).How to include zero(white) in a legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `mincnt` argument to `0` and add `"white"` to the `colramp` function, adjusting the number of colors returned from your `cols` function:

```
plot(hexbin(x,y), colorcut = seq(0,1,length.out=24), mincnt = 0,
    colramp = function(n) c("white", cols(n - 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect with my data sets!

Comment: Is there option to control the counts letter size?I have quite a huge range from 0-205.

Comment: Perhaps look at the `lcex` argument documented under `?gplot.hexbin`. If that doesn't get you what you want, please consider posting a new question.